# Laravel: belongsToMany() does not get fields in the many-to-many table

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

Consider the following tables:

```
user
  id
  name

client
  id
  name

user_client
  user_id
  client_id
  rate
  ...
```

I want my controller to get all fields in the `user` table and I also want to list their clients `name` and `rate` afterwards. User and Client models:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Client', 'user_client');
    }

}

class Client extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_client');
    }

}
```

There is no model for `user_client`.

An extract of my `UsersController@show`

```
public function show($username) // foo.com/user/{$username}
{
  $user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->firstOrFail();
  $clients = User::find($user->id)->clients;

  return View::make('users.show', compact('user', 'clients'));
}
```

While that runs fine, let's look at the view `users/show.blade.php`:

```
<h1>{{$user->name}}</h1>
@foreach($clients as $client)
  <p>{{$client->name}}, {{$client->rate}}</p>
@endforeach
```

`$client->rate` is undefined. Checking my query debuggers, belongsToMany will only select `client.*` but it doesn't select anything other than `user_id` and `client_id`.

How can I modify `User::find($user->id)->clients;` so that it will select `user_client.*` as well?

EDIT: While I'm at it, any suggestions for improvements are also welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you refer to the [laravel docs on pivot tables](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables), you will need to add `withPivot` on your relationships.

In your example you will need to add the following:

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Client', 'user_client')->withPivot('rate');
    }
}
```

Update your view like:

```
<h1>{{$user->name}}</h1>
@foreach($user->clients as $client)
    <p>{{$client->name}}, {{$client->pivot->rate}}</p>
@endforeach
```

I would also eager load the clients to save you time:

```
public function show($username) // foo.com/user/{$username}
{
    $user = User::with('clients')->where('username', '=', $username)->firstOrFail();

    return View::make('users.show', compact('user'));
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Wow that's quite nice, especially the eager loading. Looking at the docs though how would I use `public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
 {
  return new UserClient($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
 }` in this case? I've added a `BaseModel` to extend Eloquent but I'm having trouble understanding this concept.